# Argument out of range exception

Tags: c#, exception, xna

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this exception? Well I know "why" I am getting it is cause it says that the element in the list I am trying to access does not exist, but stepping through the code I can see that it actually does exist?

In Game1 I call a helper class' calculation method. Then when the calculation is done, I add the result to a List<> in the CalculationHelper class.
The code for this looks like:

In Game1 class where I have instanciated CalculationHelper calcHelper class and then call one of the class methods.
Fisrt, in Game1 I call calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(...) method in a for() loop which can be seen below. This works just fine and the calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(...) method adds the value to the IntersectionPointList<> in the CalculationHelper class (see method below).

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineList.Count; i++)
{
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);

    AddSprite(VanishingPointIntersectionList, calcHelper.GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(i), greenCirlce);
    i++;
}
```

To do some calculations and add a value to the IntersectionPointlist in CalculationHelper class I do:

```
List<Vector2> IntersectionPointList = new List<Vector2>();
public void ForceVanishingPointIntersections(Line line1, Line line2)
{
    Vector2 intersectionPoint;
    // Do some calculations

    IntersectionPointList.Add(intersectionPoint);
}
```

Finally in Game1 class, the second method in the for() loop I call AddSprite to create a Sprite. I want to pass in the values stored in CalculationHelper class IntersectionPointList as coordinates for the Sprite. 
To this end I call calcHelper.GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(i) which calls a method in CalculationHelper class like so (which should return the value at the specified point (i) from the IntersectionPointList<>)
        public Vector2 GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(int index)
        {
            Vector2 result = this.IntersectionPointList[index];
            return result;
        }
The first time the for() loop executes, this works fine. I do the calculations, the value is stored in the list and I am able to get this value from the list and pass it to AddSprite(..). However, the second time round the for() loop, when I call GetIntersectionPointListElementAt from the AddSprite() method, I get an exception in my

```
public Vector2 GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(int index)
{
    Vector2 result = this.IntersectionPointList[index];    // Exception thrown here
    return result;
}
```

saying the index was out of range? But stepping through the code, my IntersectionPointList is updated and it shows that the list now contains 2 values. And I'm trying to access the second value.

Does anyone have an idea why this could be?
For the life of me I cant figure out where I am going wrong.

If more code is needed I can post some more, just let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you access `LineList[]` with an index `i + 1` you must diminish the last index by one in the for-condition. (Note the `-1`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineList.Count - 1; i++) {
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);
    AddSprite( ... );
}
```

This will call `ForceVanishingPointIntersections` with the indexes

```
(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), ... (Count-2, Count-1)
```

Note that the index range of `LineList` is `0 ... Count-1`.

---

If non-overlapping indexes are required instead, like

```
(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), ... (Count-2, Count-1)
```

then change the loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineList.Count - 1; i += 2) {
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);
    AddSprite(
        VanishingPointIntersectionList,
        calcHelper.GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(i / 2),
        greenCirlce);
}
```

**EDIT** According the  Chris Gessler's comments this second approach is the right one.

Remove the `i++` inside the loop, it's quite uncommon and confusing. Instead, replace it by `i += 2` in loop header.

Also note that (again according to Chris Gessler) `IntersectionPointList` has half as much items as `LineList`. Therefore call `GetIntersectionPointListElementAt` with `i / 2`. Since `i` is `{0, 2, 4, ... }`,  `i / 2` is `{0, 1, 2, ...}`.

---

The for-loop allows you to have a comma-separated list of statements in the first and third section. You could use it to maintain two indexes

```
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < LineList.Count - 1; i += 2, k++) {
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);
    AddSprite(
        VanishingPointIntersectionList,
        calcHelper.GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(k),
        greenCirlce);
}
```

Comment: Did you see the OP has an extra i++ at the bottom of the loop?  It's not the best way to accomplish this, but it does diminish the last index by 1.

Comment: I did not see it, sorry. It increases the index by 2 at each loop; however, it does not diminish the last index by 1! It is still required to change the condition to `i < LineList.Count - 1`.

Comment: Quite right... but also note that the error doesn't occur until GetIntersectionPointListElementAt.  It seems to me that the LineList collection has twice as many items as the IntersectionPointList collection, but the OP is simply passing in the index i from the LineList collection.

Comment: In this case the call must be changed to `GetIntersectionPointListElementAt(i/2)`.

Comment: Thanks a million for that guys. Worked a treat. Never knew you could declare 2 values (i and k) like that in a for loop. It will come in very handy in the future. You learn something new every day

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineList.Count; i++)
{
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);

    ...

    i++;
}
```

Instead of doing that, you should do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineList.Count; i += 2)
{
    calcHelper.ForceVanishingPointIntersections(LineList[i], LineList[i + 1]);

    ...
}
```

And if LineList.Count isn't even, for example: 3.
It will start at 0, you use 0 and 1.
Then it jumps to 2, you use 2 and 3.
But oops! there isn't 3!
Only count 3! 0 to 2!

Thats when you'll get argument out of range exception.
To avoid that, you can either check if Count % 2 == 0, or you can go until LineList.Count - 1, if you don't mind skipping extra's if there are.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're adding two lines per one Sprite.  The indexes won't line up.  When LineList has 10 items, you will only have 5 IntersectionPointList items, so passing in an index of 9 will fail.

You should change your LineList collection to `List<Tuple<string,string>>` so that you have two lines per item which will line up with each Sprite.  This will create a one-to-one relationship between Lines and Sprites.

I suppose you could always pass in an index (i / 2), which should be the correct Sprite for every two lines.

Comment: +1. Good points, and thank you very much for your constructive comments.